# "Place a single square on the soil, place a firs..."

Tags: english

Place a single piece of square on the soil,
place a first stick vertically on above of a single piece of square,
place a second stick horizontally on above of the first stick,
What symbol did you get?

Comment: If you've made a mistake, just edit your original post

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu  the other one was a ring.  This one is a square.

Comment: This one is a piece of square, the last was a piece of circle. But in both questions, how many pieces of square/circle are there? Is it the same one?

Comment: @SteveV true... but I’m still considering it a duplicate because they are almost exactly the same without that one detail, the answers are very likely to be the same or similar, and were posted by the same user in rapid succession.

Comment: By “posted by the same user” I mean the questions, not the answers

Answer (score 2):

The description suggests this arrangement (if not the detail).

> [image]

Comment: That's [a symbol](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/土) all right!